# Fastest way to average sign-normalized segments of data with NumPy?

Tags: python, performance, numpy, average

What would be the fastest way to collect segments of data from a NumPy array at every point in a dataset, normalize them based on the sign (+ve/-ve) at the start of the segment, and average all segments together?

At present I have:

```
import numpy as np

x0 = np.random.normal(0,1,5000) # Dataset to be analysed

l0 = 100 # Length of segment to be averaged

def average_seg(x,l):
    return np.mean([x[i:i+l]*np.sign(x[i]) for i in range(len(x)-l)],axis=0)

av_seg = average_seg(x0,l0)
```

Timing for this is as follows:

```
%timeit average_seg(x0,l0)
22.2 ms ± 362 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

This does the job, but is there a faster way to do this?

The above code suffers when the length of x0 is large, and when the value of l0 is large. We're looking at looping through this code several million times, so even incremental improvements will help!

Comment: Note you can go the full range with `range(len(x)-l+1)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can leverage `1D convolution` -

```
np.convolve(x,np.sign(x[:-l+1][::-1]),'valid')/(len(x)-l+1)
```

The idea is to do the windowed summations with convolution and with a flipped kernel as per the [`convolution definition`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution).

Timings -

```
In [150]: x = np.random.normal(0,1,5000) # Dataset to be analysed
     ...: l = 100 # Length of segment to be averaged

In [151]: %timeit average_seg(x,l)
17.2 ms ± 689 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [152]: %timeit np.convolve(x,np.sign(x[:-l+1][::-1]),'valid')/(len(x)-l+1)
149 µs ± 3.12 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [153]: av_seg = average_seg(x,l)
     ...: out = np.convolve(x,np.sign(x[:-l+1][::-1]),'valid')/(len(x)-l+1)
     ...: print(np.allclose(out, av_seg))
True
```

**`100x+`** speedup!